# Group presentation of Integers $\big(\mathbb{Z,+}\big)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I can't understand how is it possible to represent the group  $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ as follows $$\mathbb{Z} = \big<a\big>$$

with only one generator and no relations ? How can there be no relations in the group presentation ? ($\color{blue}{is \space it \space a \space free \space group ?} $ ) and if not then there must be a relation. I found that in wikipedia [Here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)

Also since $a$ is a generator, then it should be $1$ right ?

there is no other single generators for $\mathbb{Z}$ other than $1$.

If we allow two generators then we can have something like $2,3$ because $2,3$ are coprimes and so $3-2 = 1$ and we can represent any integer as a linear combination of those two integers because $\color{purple}{\gcd(2,3) = 1}$

Another question that came to my mind is the following

> I know that given a group presentation with relations $R$ one can deduce all other relations in the group from the set $R$. Now I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group with the relation that $a + b = b+ a \space \forall \space a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>    $\color{red}{Question}$ How can one get that abelian relation using that group presentation with no relations what so ever ?

Comment: It is a free group (with a single generator), why do you think any differently? Think about what elements in $\langle a \rangle$ look like, and it should be easy to see that the map defined by sending $1$ to $a$ and extended in the natural way is a group isomorphism.

Comment: @Hayden A free group is a group that has no relations other than the inverse relations (Because it is a group after all). So now you are saying that the group of integers with the addition operation is an example of a free group ??

Comment: Why do you assert it is not a free group?

Comment: @alkabary A free group generated by a set $S$ has no relations **between the elements of $S$**.   Sure, $a+b=b+a$ is a relation on the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, but when you represent $a$ and $b$ as either sums of $1$'s or sums of $-1$'s, then relative to the element of $1$, there's really nothing more being said here than a trivial equality.

Comment: Also your statement "there is no other single generator for ${\mathbb Z}$ other than $1$" is wrong. $-1$ is also a single generator.

Comment: You can think about it multiplicatively if you want. The free group on one letter $g$ is the set of words $g^n$ for integers $n\in\Bbb Z$. But of course $g^ng^m=g^{n+m}$ (this relation is true for any letter $g$ in **any** free group whatsoever), so this free group on one letter is just $\Bbb Z$ in disguise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb Z$ is a free group. We can let $S=\{1\}$ and then indeed have the defining property of free group: For any group $G$ and map $f\colon S\to G$ there exists one and only one group homomoprhism $\phi\colon\mathbb Z\to G$ with the property that $\phi(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in S$. This is just a highbrow formulation for the homomoprhism $n\mapsto f(1)^n$.

There is another one-element set that generates $\mathbb Z$, namely $\{-1\}$. So we have $\mathbb Z=\langle 1\rangle=\langle -1\rangle$.
In both cases there is no relation for the genearator $a$. Infact, such a relation could only have the form $a^n=1$ (written multiplicatiuvely!) and that would make $\langle\,a\mid a^n=1\,\rangle=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb Z$.

The relation that $\mathbb Z$ is abelian is automatic from it being cyclic. Note that the relation would have to be written as $a^na^m=a^ma^n$, but this relation is trivially correct (and hence redundant) because both sides are just $a^{n+m}=a^{m+n}$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense ! thanks :)